# Consistent error accessing Soundcloud API with PHP on bluehost server

Tags: php, api, soundcloud, bluehost

I'm having trouble with Soundcloud.php on my server. Although it runs just fine on my MAMP installation. Basically my test page won't load and an error is logged declaring a problem in Soundcloud.php:

```
[03-Apr-2012 03:50:57] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home2/mysite/public_html/mysubdomain/Soundcloud.php on line 685
```

the test code is fine - here it is for reference:

```
<?php

require 'Soundcloud.php';

$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud('Client_ID','Client_Secret', 'Redirect_URI');

try {
$info = json_decode($soundcloud->get('tracks', array('user_id' => 'blumarten')), true);
print_r($info);
}
catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

I just had the account upgraded to PHP 5.3 but the error still occurs, any ideas?

Comment: newline conversion issue maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have any ideas on how to check for such an issue?

Comment: Hi Joe - I'm really just guessing. Most decent text editors will allow you to change a file from windows line endings to mac to unix. If you get desperate you could use a hex editor.

Comment: Can you include line 685 from `Soundcloud.php` and a couple of lines around it?

Comment: Have you verified that you are in fact running PHP 5.3? The error message would indicate that you are not or that anonymous functions are otherwise not supported (line 685 of Soundcloud.php in the SoundCloud PHP SDK is a call to array_map passing it an anonymous function).

Comment: Thanks for your your replies guys. I just ran the check and it is in fact php 5.2.17 - I guess for some reason I thought their latest would be 5.3. Might I be able to just edit this to be a normal function to run the script? I'm just getting into PHP after learning some C programming so sorry if that's a silly question!

Comment: Hi guys, I've got them to up the server to php 5.3- but I now get 2 errors

PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in /home2/mysite/public_html/mysubdomain/Soundcloud.php on line 685

Comment: You need to get your host to disable magic_quotes_gpc in their php.ini settings (or you can if that's something you have control over).

Comment: Thanks so much, I did that but I'm still getting the T_STRING error!

Comment: Hi Joe, it's definitely something to do with the PHP version / configuration on your server. Is your hosting company able to help? They'll have access to configuration information that nobody here will have access to.

Comment: Hi Paul- I asked for a fresh clean install of the PHP with standard settings but they refused as it is a shared server- thanks a lot for your help though- hopefully I'll get it running someday soon. Keep up the good work with soundcloud :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoundCloud PHP API and documentation are very poor and buggy at the moment , hopefully will get better.

Replace this code around line 720

```
$postData = array_map(function ($track) {
    return 'playlist[tracks][][id]=' . $track;
}, $trackIds);
```

With this:

```
$postData = array_map("suckySc", $trackIds);
```

And add this function to the top of the file, before the class opening:

```
function suckySc ($track){
    return 'playlist[tracks][][id]=' . $track;
}
```